# NancyFx won't serve static content (images) from a folder called '16x16'

Tags: nancy, static-content

I have a NancyFx (v0.21.1) web site where some of my images are held in a subfolder of the content folder, e.g.: /content/img/16x16/image.png

However, Nancy won't serve this image (yields a 404).  If I change the folder name to something else (/content/img/size16/image.png), Nancy will serve the image.

Not the end of the world (clearly), but interested to know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What hosting are you using? I just tried this using `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet` for the latest build (1.4.3) and it works fine

[image]

0.21.1 is over 2 years old and a lot has changed during that time. I wouldn't be surprised if there used to be an encoding issue that has been resolved since

If you really want to figure it out, then I recommend you grab the PDB files and step into the static content convention and see what is happening